# Hadoop start-dfs.sh could not start nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While I was trying to start a hdfs on my localhost server, something went wrong.

After `ssh localhost` `hdfs namenode -format`, I tried to run `start-dfs.sh`. Everything seemed to be on track because my zsh did not recognize the java error and ticked green for me. However when I tried to check the daemon with `jps`, I could not find my nodes working.

Then I dug deeper into the log. The data/name/secondary node all logged the following error similar to below (I picked datanode as example):

`2021-11-13 23:44:46,791 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM`

`2021-11-13 23:44:46,791 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 1: SIGHUP`

Then I referred to some of the solutions to the former error 15, they all told me to simply restart the daemon. However, after running `stop-all.sh` and reformatting the namenode, these errors remain unchanged. And now I doubt whether I was wrong during some of the steps setting up the hadoop.

I got my changed file listed below:

`core-site.xml`:

```
        <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`:

```
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
     </property>
```

`mapred-site.xml`:

```
   <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
```

`yarn-site.xml`:

```
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
     <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
```

ps: My hadoop-env seemed to have been configured properly because java is running normally. Plus, I don't think there is any environment variable problem in this case. Also, `ssh localhost` seemed to be working fine during the period. At least no error was reported while using ssh.

However, I'm ready to get these related files posted if the problem is in these cases.

Comment: Can you share the namenode logs? Hope you would have set HADOOP_HOME & other environment variables properly

Comment: Try running `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` directly and provide more of the logs for either (start with getting a running namenode)

Comment: @OneCricketeer In this way(`hadoop namenode`) no `SIGHUP` is hanging up my process,  and namenode works fine. However, is there any solutions to not let it occupy a terminal? For it does not let me use the terminal that I opened it with.

Comment: Oh modifying your two commands into `nohup hdfs namenode &` and `nohup hdfs datanode &` also makes them works well background with `nohup ssh localhost &`. However, I'm interested what happened to `start-dfs.sh`? I haven't modified it but why did it not work?

Comment: You don't need ssh unless you use start dfs command. So, sounds like that was a problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer Okay then. I'll flag the question solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eicc Is the solution you posted below the solution that worked? It looks more like a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Dharman I have the problem solved by substituting the `start-dfs.sh` with the three `nohup` commands above. I just consider this expedient a solution.

Comment: Please add it as an answer below. Don't add it as an edit or a comment to the question. Please use the answer space provided